# How to fix Azure pipeline ( /templates/test-template.yaml (Line: 5, Col: 8): Unexpected value '') Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up an gradle azure yaml pipeline that uses test_template.yaml, and when i run pipeline i get  Unexpected value ''
My question is how can i improve my template or fix it ?

```
trigger: none

variables:
  - group: azurecr  #azure container registry

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
stages:
  stage: test
  jobs:
    - template: templates/test_template.yaml
      parameters:
        app: :mortgage:mortgage-app:test
```

Build and test template

```
#  build  and test template

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - task:
    inputs: 
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'  #gradle wrapper file
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m' # max memory 
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11' #java version 
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64' 
      publishJUnitResults: true 
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      tasks: 'build'
  - bash: | 
      echo "Build and run unit tests ${{ parameters.app }}". 
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameters.tag }};]$(./gradlew ${{ parameters.app }}} -q printVersion)" #build and run test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job requires to have name

> - job: string # Required as first property. ID of the job. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '_' and may not start
>   with a number.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines

For example

```
- job:MyJobName
```

EDIT 1
Also Azure DevOps will not know what task do you want to run in this place, you need to provide task name

```
  - task:
    inputs:
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops

EDIT 2
If you provide parameters to template you need to state in this template that it will accept this parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters

So on the beginning of the template should be

```
parameters:
- name: app
  type: string
```